# Collapsible Animations triggered by checkboxes

Tags: css, animation

I was wondering if someone could help me with an animation. I have collapsing divs, triggered by hidden check boxes. I can animate the check boxes, but the divs themselves don't animate. I've tried setting transitions on multiple classes, but no luck, and I admit, I'm not strong in CSS. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Sans-serif", Arial;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #435757;
}
div.main {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}
div.content {      
  border-left: 3px solid;
  border-color: #0066cc;
  padding-left: 15px;      
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
div.labeltab {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.toggle-box {
  display: none;
}
.toggle-box + label {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
.toggle-box + label:hover {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.toggle-box + label + div {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.toggle-box:checked + label {
  color: #0066cc;
  font-style: italic;
}
.toggle-box:checked + label + div {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.toggle-box + label:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-right: 3px solid;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.toggle-box:checked + label:before {
  content: "";
  color: #0066cc;
  border-right: 3px solid;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="LabelTab"><input class="toggle-box" id="identifier-8" name="grouped" type="checkbox"><label for="identifier-8"> Test 1</label>
<div>
<div class="content">
<h4>Content 1</h4>
<p>Stuff</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="LabelTab"><input class="toggle-box" id="identifier-6" name="grouped" type="checkbox"><label for="identifier-6">Test 2</label>
<div>
<div class="content">
<h4>Content 2</h4>
<p>Stuff</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: accordion CSS can also involve :focus . an example with :focus & :checked side by side https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/dsvwF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't transition `display` but you can transition `opacity` and `max-height`

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Sans-serif", Arial;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #435757;
}
div.main {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
div.content {
  border-left: 3px solid;
  border-color: #0066cc;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
div.labeltab {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.toggle-box {
  display: none;
}
.toggle-box + label {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
.toggle-box + label:hover {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.toggle-box + label + div {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.toggle-box:checked + label {
  color: #0066cc;
  font-style: italic;
}
.toggle-box:checked + label + div {
  max-height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.toggle-box + label:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-right: 3px solid;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.toggle-box:checked + label:before {
  content: "";
  color: #0066cc;
  border-right: 3px solid;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="LabelTab"><input class="toggle-box" id="identifier-8" name="grouped" type="checkbox"><label for="identifier-8"> Test 1</label>
  <div>
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Content 1</h4>
      <p>Stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="LabelTab"><input class="toggle-box" id="identifier-6" name="grouped" type="checkbox"><label for="identifier-6">Test 2</label>
  <div>
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Content 2</h4>
      <p>Stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for in terms of appearance, thank you! I do have a problem though. My Divs are varying heights. It looks like CSS can only calulate animations if it has fixed parameters like max-height:0px to max-height:100px. If i try to do 100% of the div, it picks 100% or the window area at the current page load, something like 980px. my divs vary from 1100 to 600. Am a correct in assuming this limitation? or is there any other choices?

Comment: @TStone that's correct, it's a limitation of a CSS only approach. To do it dynamically without needing to know the approximate height of each box, you would need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I got it thanks to Michael! I set a min-height and max-height with in my content ranges, in the .toggle-box:checked + label + div and it works. Now i have multiple height, animated matched divs. Thanks!

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Sans-serif", Arial;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #435757;
}
div.main {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
div.content {
  border-left: 3px solid;
  border-color: #0066cc;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
div.labeltab {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.toggle-box {
  display: none;
}
.toggle-box + label {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
.toggle-box + label:hover {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.toggle-box + label + div {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.toggle-box:checked + label {
  color: #0066cc;
  font-style: italic;
}
.toggle-box:checked + label + div {
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 1200px;
  opacity: 1; 
  margin-right: auto;
}
.toggle-box + label:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-right: 3px solid;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.toggle-box:checked + label:before {
  content: "";
  color: #0066cc;
  border-right: 3px solid;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="LabelTab"><input class="toggle-box" id="identifier-8" name="grouped" type="checkbox"><label for="identifier-8"> Test 1</label>
  <div>
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Content 1</h4>
      <p>Stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="LabelTab"><input class="toggle-box" id="identifier-6" name="grouped" type="checkbox"><label for="identifier-6">Test 2</label>
  <div>
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Content 2</h4>
      <p>Stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```